# Angular / Ionic: Access function property from other function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, packery

I am using [Packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co/) to allow my cards to flow better, and I initialize the grid in a function called from `ionViewDidEnter()`.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.clientService.clientStream$.subscribe(
    client => {
      this.client = client;  
      this.setupGrid();
    }
  )
}

setupGrid() {

  setTimeout(()=> {

    var elem = document.querySelector('.pckry-grid');

    var pckry = new Packery( elem, {
      itemSelector: ".grid-item"
    });

    // Resets the grid after elements have loaded
    pckry.layout()

    // attempt at saving pckry object to component variable
    this.packery = pckry

    console.log(this.packery)

  }, 1);
}
```

This works, however, when there is a change in the layout, I need to be able to call `pckry.layout()` from a function that detects the change.  I've attempted the following with no luck:

```
// this is called when a form input is changed and I'd like to refresh the layout
formHasChanged() {
  this.formChanged = true;
  this.setupGrid();
}
```

I've tried calling `this.packery.layout()` from within `formHasChanged()` but that didn't work either.  Is there a better way to reference to make this work?

Comment: Where do you call `formHasChanged()`?

Comment: How about using ChangeDetectorRef and ChangeDetectionStrategy? Please see if this link helps you out https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Comment: @echonax I call it here: `<form #profileForm="ngForm" class="profile-form" name="profileForm" (change)="formHasChanged()">...</form>`

Comment: I think I may not be explaining myself.  The `formHasChanged()` function and the `setupGrid()` function are called, but nothing happens to my DOM.  The packery function call has no effect.  I figured I needed to reference it differently